# How to pass a Perl/CGI variable into my PHP script

Tags: perl, variables

I am under the unfortunate circumstance of having to work on some really old software for my company - it is written in either Perl or CGI, the page uses both and I don't know the difference. I only do PHP.

The problem is that there is a Perl variable - $cateogory.name$ - on a page, and I have to figure out how to get that variable into a PHP variable so that I can run a function on that variable in PHP.

I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Could you pass it on as a variable? That would probably be fine if it's not sensitive (and assuming that it would be OK for it to be used as a link). I don't know perl... but if you could have a hyperlink like this: phppage.php?categoryname=$cateogory.name$, then you could read it in php with: $category = $_GET['cateogory'];

That would be one way of going about it. I suppose you could pass it through with as a POST or SESSION variable... or even as a cookie.